# PHP/MySql insert statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have never done this before, and this is the first time I have encountered this situation

Here is my code that I created:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customerinfo (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, Email, Symptoms) VALUES ('', '{$first}', '{$last}', {$codearea}, {$threedigit}, {$fourdigit}, '{$email}')", $connection);
```

As you can see, I have table that has 6 columns, which are:

1. CustomerInfo
2. FirstName
3. LastName
4. PhoneNumber
5. Email
6. Symptoms

Now, when a client fills out the form, it should insert it into the database.
However, if you look at my insert statement, I listed PhoneNumber column 3 times because the form has 3 fields(code area, prefix, and line number) on the HTML page, and I want all three fields insert into the PhoneNumber column. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is screaming *SQL Injection*.

Comment: @Martin How do you know? Maybe user is filtering the input somewhere else....or maybe not

Comment: He's said in comments the strings are properly escaped.

Comment: it can't be if i'm using htmlspecialchars();

Comment: Let's say it so: If I'd get asked this question in RL I would have a look at the form data handling as well - just to make sure.

Comment: Martin, do you want to see my code?

Comment: No, I'll believe without seeing. :-)

Comment: I have no problem posting it. I'm not asking for SQL Injection simply because I don't know much about it.

Comment: You should probably use `mysql_real_escape_string($str)` instead.

Comment: @Tim mysql_real_escape_string won't help him

Comment: "it can't be if i'm using htmlspecialchars()", LOL

Comment: To be fair, while `htmlspecialchars` may not be a good choice, it WILL escape strings... just, his database will be full of special characters instead of the quotes that long to be there. However, if he's rendering into a purely HTML environment, it WOULD work...

Comment: It was my mistake, I wanted to say mysql_real_escape_string instead of htmlspecialchars. Htmlspecialchars is for injecting html tags.

Comment: @Tim you said that. **strings**. But there is data that is NOT a string. Go figure.

Comment: you are still vulnerable to injection, despite of the function you're used in a manner of magical chant

Comment: so, what is your solution, Col? I would like to know, so that I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: There is an answer below. If you didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the values into a single string before executing the query.

```
$phone = $codearea . $threedigit . $fourdigit;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customerinfo (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email, Symptoms) VALUES ('', '{$first}', '{$last}', '{$phone}', '{$email}')", $connection);
```

Comment: If you feel my solution does not answer the *question* please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate those with a `.` in PHP and insert as a single field. You could do something similar in MySQL but it is a bit more messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're prompting for separate areacode/prefix/line data in the form, you should keep them separate in the database as well - three separate fields instead of a single "phone number" fields.

However, if that's not possible, then concatenate the values in PHP:

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., PhoneNumber, ...) VALUES (..., '{$codearea}-{$threedigit}-{$fourdigit}', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use PHP to merge the 3 HTML form fields together before you insert:

`$vPhoneNumber` `= $part1 . $part2 . $part3`

You can then insert `$vPhonenumber` in your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store all related phone values, **like** this:

```
$phoneNumber = $_POST['codearea'] + " " + $_POST['threedigit'] + " " + $_POST['fourdigit'];
```

Then, change your query to:

```
INSERT INTO customerinfo 
(CustomerInfo, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email, Symptoms) 
VALUES 
('', '{$first}', '{$last}', '{$phoneNumber}', '{$email}')", $connection);
```

This aproach you're using will difficult your work if you have to present the data from the database to html, in 3 fields. Probably you'll need "explode" the phone string in 3. Would be better if you were using only one html field or 3 collumns in your database table.

Comment: Why are there spaces between the fields? What if one of the POST variables contains a space? @user1183022 Do you ever want to separate this information again? If not, why use three fields in your form?

Comment: @Martin, do you noticed the "...<b>like</b> this:" ?  Is just an example of he can do.

Comment: @user just be prepared to some unexpected results... from the answer you was looking for.

Comment: @user1183022, if my answer, or any other, was what you looked for, please mark it as correct (for a better Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO customerinfo (
        CustomerInfo, 
        FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        PhoneNumber, 
        Email, 
        Symptoms
    ) VALUES (
        '', 
        '".$first."', 
        '".$last."', 
        '".$codearea.$threedigit.$fourdigit."', 
        '".$email."',
        '".$symptoms."'
    )", $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to store three values in one field.

You must

- either use three columns for PhoneNumber (code area, prefix, and line number)
- or somehow make one value out of the three (e.g. by making a csv string out of it).

Answer (score -1):

PHP `mysql_` is deprecated, use http://php.net/pdo instead.

Properly escape your column names and use PDO prepared statements to set bindings.

```
INSERT INTO `customerinfo` (`CustomerInfo`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES (:customer_info, :first_name, :last_name);
```

Once you have this, you can execute the query like this.

```
$sth    = $db->prepare([the query from the above]);
$sth->execute(array('customer_info' => implode('; ', array([data that you want to concatenate])), 'first_name' => 'name', 'last_name' => 'name'));
```

Comment: Good advice but it doesn't really answer the question!

Comment: They are properly escape(I don't think that I need single quotes for numeric values, right?); I need $codearea, $threedigit, and $foudigit insert into PhoneNumber column.

Comment: @user1183022 You expect those values to be numeric, but what if they aren't?

Comment: Did you even read his question?  He has three variables in php he wants to stick into one field.  He just needs to use string concatenation, not re-vamp his knowledge of mysql APIs.

Comment: @Guy because he was asking how to merge 3 HTML form fields and place them into ONE database field... PDO / Prepared Statements i agree is good advice but it doesn't offer the solution. Also Down voting my answer is a low blow ;-)

Comment: @diagonalbatman Seriously? (1) I didn't even bother to read the question since the title said "PHP/MySql insert statement not working". Supposedly, the issue is escaping. (2) If you see someone on fire and he comes to ask you for directions to a fire station do you: (a) give him directions or (b) try to put-off the fire. I hope it is not (a).

Comment: Now I see at least 5 answers which are completely wrong, at least in terms of security. Good job on encouraging best practices.

Comment: @Guy - are you really saying you didn't bother to read the question before posting your answer!? Wow....

Comment: @Guy - great best practice is one thing, but the chap didn't ask "What is the best way of doing this" he asked "Why cant i get this to work"

Comment: He also asked in a wrong way. I've read the important bits (title, query), without continuing into his grammatical mess.

Comment: Seriously?  You're saying now that his grammar is at fault and you didn't read the question itself?  He's already escaping his fields, anyway.  Even your PDO query is wrong (missing colon on field).

Comment: Guys, it was just a question...no need to argue. Besides, my first language is not English,

Comment: @diagonalbatman, grow up. I am saying that I generally don't read through all the question, because the question is most often clear from the title. Thanks for correcting "PDO query". Good luck.

Comment: @Tim however it is proposed for deprecation. in fact, nobody in the team wishes to be a supporter. that's the only reason but it will lead to deprecation.